# Iframe Scroll bar is not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scrollbar, mousewheel

I have created an Iframe with following attributes.

```
<iframe id='modalIframeId' width='100%' height='100%' name='modalIframeId'  marginWidth='0' marginHeight='0'   frameBorder='0' scrolling='auto' scrolling='yes'  title='Dialog Title'>
```

When I scroll top to bottom with mouse wheel the content is going fine.but the scroll bar is not moving accordingly.This is the same scenario with IE8 and firefox .How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see after your 100% width and height that you wanna make the whole page an iframe.

You'd can better your `<frame>` and `<frameset>`, but using ajax or php is allways the best.

```
<frameset cols="100%">
    <frame src="document.html">
</frameset>

<?php include 'document.html'; ?>  



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$.get("document.html", function(data){
    document.write(data)
});
</script>
```